# Compose an email with an inline image

Tags: mail.app

Some time ago I managed to force Mail to always put attachments at the end of the email. Now I would like to revert this setting.

As I don't find anything in the GUI (preferences) I suppose that I changed some preferences with the terminal.

I see that I have `AttachAtEnd=1` in my preferences

```
> defaults read com.apple.mail  | grep AttachAtEnd
AttachAtEnd = 1;
```

But it seems that I am not able to change it

```
> defaults write com.apple.com AttachAtEnd -bool No
> defaults read com.apple.mail  | grep AttachAtEnd
AttachAtEnd = 1;
```

or

```
> defaults delete com.apple.com AttachAtEnd
> defaults read com.apple.mail  | grep AttachAtEnd
AttachAtEnd = 1;
```

How can I remove it?

Comment: How did you manage to NOT inline your attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using `com.apple.com` rather than `com.apple.mail` in your `defaults write` or `defaults delete` commands.

`defaults delete com.apple.mail AttachAtEnd` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks I really don't know where the typo is coming from...